# cloudkit enter userID as reference of a new record (in code)

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckreference

I am setting an app in which a user could create records. Let's say he/she is the owner of a chatroom. Therefore there is an attribute called "admin" in the chatroom record. This attribute takes a reference which is the ID of the owner.

Here is what I tried:

```
CKContainer.defaultContainer().fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler({
            userRecordID, error in
            if error != nil {
                println("caca")
            } else {
                println("gettin close")
                let UserRecordIDToStore = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(userRecordID)
                let iDString = userRecordID.recordName as String
                daMainUser.setObject(iDString, forKey: "user")
            }
            })
```

When I pass iDString as above, and I create the record (the room), its admin reference is empty. Whether I did cast iDString as a String or not.

When I pass userRecordID directly, I get an error: 
'CKRecordID' is not identical to 'CKRecordValue'

I have been looking everywhere but I cannot find more information about this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your user field is set up as a CKReference field, then you should set it like this:

```
daMainUser.setObject(CKReference(recordID: userRecordID, action: CKReferenceAction.None), forKey: "user")
```

In your case you do not have to create a recordID because you already have it. Otherwise you had to create it with something like:

```
var recordID = CKRecordID(recordName: userRecordID.recordName)
```

Comment: Hi Edwin, thank you very much for your answer. The problem is that when I enter open the parentheses after CKReference, I can't choose (recordID: ..., forKey: ...) Instead I can only choose 

1: CKReference(coder: ...)   
2: CKReference(record: ..., action: ...) 
3: CKReference(recordID: ..., action: ...)

When I enter     daMainUser.setObject(CKReference(recordID: userRecordID, forKey: "user")

I get an error: Extra argument 'recordID' in call

My version of Xcode is 6.1.1 don't know if that can help.

Comment: sorry, that was a cut and past bug. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I appreciate it. But it seems like I am facing bad luck on this one. I entered the correct line from above, but the "user" reference of the record is still empty, while other attributes (date, name) where successfully saved. Any idea?